# iPhone 6 broadcasts two IP address's of which are identical, except for last set of numbers; possible clone of hacked iPhone?

Tags: iphone

When running ettercap on Kali Linux using my cellular connection from AT&T, i monitored the web traffic of my iPhone 6 of which I believe has been hacked by ex boyfriend. What was incredibly strange and without any plausible explanation, there were two external IP's broadcasting,  as if they were clones of one another. They had the exact same configuration with the exact same ports open, with the only true difference being the last set of numbers on the IP. Is cloning an iPhone or perhaps the SIM being cloned a feasible explanation and are there any other sure fire methods of determining what is going on with my phone?

Comment: Were the two IPS at exactly the same time or when did they switch?

Comment: when using cellular data your phone will obtain a differnt IP address at least every time the tower changes.

Comment: If your SIM was cloned, you wouldn't be seeing traffic from the cloned SIM when monitoring your own phone's connection.